# Vulkan validation layers not working unless using Vulkan Configurator

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm creating a Vulkan game engine and I'm trying to implement validation layers into my application. To test it I tried to destroy my `VkInstance` before the `VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` but it produces no output! When I have the Vulkan Configurator app open the error appears and it uses my `VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` callback function to print the output. So I don't think its the debug messenger that's the problem.

I'm using Vulkan 1.3.250.1 and I`m on Windows.

Here is the code of me enabling the layers:

```cpp
if (m_enableValidationLayers) {
    uint32_t layerCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkLayerProperties> supportedLayers{ layerCount };
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, supportedLayers.data());

    uint32_t supportedLayerCount = 0;

    for (const char* requiredLayer : m_validationLayers)
        for (const VkLayerProperties& supportedLayers : supportedLayers)
            if (strcmp(requiredLayer, supportedLayers.layerName) == '\0') supportedLayerCount++;

    I_DEBUG_ASSERT_FATAL_ERROR(supportedLayerCount != m_validationLayers.size(), "Required Vulkan validation layers not supported!");

    instanceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = (uint32_t)m_validationLayers.size();
    instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = m_validationLayers.data();

    instanceExtensions.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME);
}
```

`m_validationLayers` contains `"VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"`.

The assert passes and the `VkInstance` creates successfully.

I checked the values in my debugger and they all seem the check out.

My debug messenger also creates successfully.

I've heard of other having problems outside of code, so I decided to reinstall Vulkan to the newest version currently available (Vulkan 1.3.250.1) but that didn't fix it.